# JSOUP converting original html to some additional encoded values

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

My intial html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" class="SAF" id="global-header-light">
<head>

</head>
<body>


<div style="background-image: url(http://aka-cdn-ns.adtech.de/rm/ads/23274/HPWomenLOFT_1381687318.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-background-size: 1001px 2059px; height: 2059px; width: 1001px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">                      

<div style="height:2058px; padding-left:0px; padding-top:36px;">


<iframe style="height:90px; width:728px;" />



</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

After I use doc.html() from JSOUP the JSOUP parser adds additional encoded values at end of Iframe element.The changed html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" class="SAF" id="global-header-light">
 <head> 
  <style>

</style> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div style="background-image: url(aol.jpeg); background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:90720;height:720; width:90; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;"> 
   <div style="height:450; width:100; padding-left:681px; padding-top:200px;"> 
    <iframe style="height:1050px; width:300px;"></iframe> ***&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/body&gt; &lt;/html&gt;***
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Please help me how to avoid this.

Thanks
Swaraj

Answer (score 0):

If you parse it using `xmlParser` it won't add the additional values. For example:

```
String html = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
                "<html xmlns:og=\"http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/\" xmlns:fb=\"http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\" lang=\"en\" class=\"SAF\" id=\"global-header-light\">" +
                "<head></head>" +
                "<body>" +
                "<div style=\"background-image: url(http://aka-cdn-ns.adtech.de/rm/ads/23274/HPWomenLOFT_1381687318.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-background-size: 1001px 2059px; height: 2059px; width: 1001px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;\">" +
                "<div style=\"height:2058px; padding-left:0px; padding-top:36px;\">" +
                "<iframe style=\"height:90px; width:728px;\" /></div></div></body></html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
System.out.println(doc);
```

Will output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" class="SAF" id="global-header-light">
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div style="background-image: url(http://aka-cdn-ns.adtech.de/rm/ads/23274/HPWomenLOFT_1381687318.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-background-size: 1001px 2059px; height: 2059px; width: 1001px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
   <div style="height:2058px; padding-left:0px; padding-top:36px;">
    <iframe style="height:90px; width:728px;"></iframe>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

You could first get the remote file as a String and then use the rest of my code as normal:

```
String url = request.getParameter("htmluri").trim(); 
System.out.println("Fetching %s..."+url); 
String xml = Jsoup.connect(url).get().toString();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

`Parser.xmlParser()` is a part of Jsoup (see http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html).

Comment: can you let me know how you will modify this code to match your suggestion                                                      String url = request.getParameter("htmluri").trim();
        System.out.println("Fetching %s..."+url);

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

Comment: what library to include for Parser,xmlParser()

Comment: @SwarajChhatre See my updated answer. Please upvote/accept if this solves your problem.